# Script to copy 4000 rows +

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working with a copy script that works fine with minimal rows. I have a form response sheet that will grow up to 4000 rows before i clean it out. I want to copy the response sheet to another google project sheet but my script keeps timing out or doesn't run at all. I need an efficient script to copy large amounts of data to several different spreadsheets. I'm sure this is cake for the Pro's here, I'm still learning.

Here's my script:

```js
function CopyRange() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('myspreadsheet-ID'); //replace with source ID
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet4'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var range = ss.getRange('A:Q'); //assign the range you want to copy
  var data = range.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Destination-spreadsheet-ID'); //replace with destination ID
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('data collect'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,4000,15).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of 
  the copied data see getRange()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function copyStuffToSeveralSpreadsheets() {
  var ssA=['ssid1','ssid2','ssid3'.....];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('mySSID');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),17);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  ssA.forEach(function(r,i){
    var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssA[i]); 
    var tsh=tss.getSheetByName('data collect');
    tsh.clearContents();//remove to append
    tsh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);//remove to append
    //tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);//enable this to append to the bottom of last dataset
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried running your code using 1 destination spreadsheet "ssid1"  ....I seems to be doing the same thing my code did. It runs until it times out. I tried making the reference data sheet smaller, like 2,000 rows and still no luck. Ideally I would like to transfer at least 4,000 rows with 1 run.

Comment: I just took this code as is and copied 2000 rows 20 columns of mostly numbers too 3 files.  It ran in less  then 15 seconds.  So I'm guessing you probably have some anomalies in your date.  Are copying to or from a shared drive.  Please provide application specific details that might affect the transfers at this point all details are in question since we don't know whats wrong.

Comment: I ran it again with 5000 rows 20 column of mostly numbers and I'm appending it now and the execution time was 24 seconds.

Comment: Check your executions to make sure that you not getting any errors there.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I think maybe I'm not inserting the spreadsheet ID properly. I copied your code and inserted the destination ssid between the apostrophes on the first line of code. For starters I'm only transferring the data to one separate sheet, so I deleted the rest of the line to the ] bracket. Forgive me for the inexperience, I'm still learning coding. I do really appreciate your help and I think I'm getting close. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Also, does the amount of formulas in the destination spreadsheet hold any weight on this data transfer? The destination SS is pretty heavy with formulas and queries....Thx again

Comment: I got the script to run a few times. It's still very slow. I have a google business suite with only one other user. The data contains both numbers and text. The destination sheet has 33 tabs and it's loaded with formulas. I wonder if that's the issue?